# retrieve data from database and assign it into array

Tags: php

```
function get_name(){
    global $con;
    $sql= "SELECT name FROM `hotels`";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   // echo"<p> num of name $count </p>";

  $name=array();


 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
  {         
      $name[$i]=$row[$i];
      //print_r ($name);

  }
 }

    return $name;
 }
```

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Also why have the `for`? The `while` handles the iteration. Just have `$name[]=$row['name'];`

Answer (score 0):

As chris85 commented you are looping for the count of the result and in each iteration you do another inner loop that fetches the results of the query, starting from the second iteration of the outer loop the `$row` is `null` because all rows has been already fetched in the first iteration.

replace this part of your code

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $name[$i]=$row[$i];
        //print_r ($name);
    }
}
```

with this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $name[]=$row['name'];
}
```